# If the female comparator to the Oedipus complex is Electra complex, is there a male comparator to Jocasta/Phaedra complex?

Tags: abnormal-psychology, sexuality, psychoanalysis, parenting

I have been browsing the questions and answers here within the realm of psychoanalysis and I came across [the Jocasta complex in an answer here](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/3803/7604), which I had not heard about before so I have been looking at this.

There is of course [Freud and Jung's theory regarding child to parent attraction](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/9344/7604) which is well known in Psychology. So, we have the male [**Oedipus complex**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oedipus_complex) (Freudian for the son's sexual desires for the mother) and we have the female [**Electra complex**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electra_complex) (Jungian for the daughter's sexual desires for the father).

I have now found out that there is [Raymond de Saussure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raymond_de_Saussure)'s and [controversial](https://www.upi.com/Archives/1980/09/26/A-controversial-view-of-homosexuality/3805338788800/) psychiatrist, Alfred Ames Messer's theories, regarding parent to child attraction. We have the [**Jocasta complex**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jocasta_complex) [the mother's sexual desires for the son] ([De Saussure, 1920](https://www.pep-web.org/document.php?id=IZPA.006.0118A)) and I have also just found out there is the [**Phaedra complex**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phaedra_complex) [the stepmother's sexual desires for the stepson] ([Messer, 1969](https://doi.org/10.1001/archpsyc.1969.01740200085012)).

I must admit, I do have an issue with these two so-called complexes, but it made me wonder if there are comparators to these where the father has sexual desires for their daughter or stepfather for their stepdaughter.

> Combien de mère ne sont-elles pas amoureuses de leur fils? Combien de pères ne sont-ils par amoureux de leur fille?
>
> [How many mothers are not in love with their son? How many fathers are not in love with their daughter?]
> ([De Saussure, 1920](https://www.pep-web.org/document.php?id=IZPA.006.0118A))

I can't seem to find any male parent "complexes" when searching online but I can obviously find the [chronophilia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronophilia) terms paedophilia, [hebephilia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebephilia) and [ephebophilia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephebophilia) which to me equally define female sexual attraction to those under the [age of consent to sex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_consent) (which differs worldwide).

[If paedophilia/hebephilia/ephebophilia is to be considered a sexual orientation](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/587/7604), surely there would be a male comparator?

| Female comparator | Male comparator |
| --- | --- |
| Electra Complex | Oedipus Complex |
| Jocasta Complex | ? |
| Phaedra Complex | ? |

### References

De Saussure, R. (1920). Le complexe de Jocaste. *Internationale Zeitschrift für Psychoanalyse, 6*(2), 118-122. https://www.pep-web.org/document.php?id=IZPA.006.0118A

Messer, A. A. (1969). The phaedra complex. *Archives of general psychiatry, 21*(2), 213-218. https://doi.org/10.1001/archpsyc.1969.01740200085012